# iOS app was rejected repeatedly from appstore due to : 2.2 Apps that exhibit bugs will be rejected

Tags: ios, ipad, app-store, app-store-connect, ios9

I'm so worried about new issue with submitting app to appstore. They gives me error in resolution center, but i can't reproduce the issue. I don't know what's wrong on my code. Please guide me to resolve this issue. Because app was rejected again and again.

**From Apple**

```
2.2 - Apps that exhibit bugs will be rejected
```

**2.2 Details**

We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on **iPad running iOS 9.0.2** on both Wi-Fi and cellular networks.

***We found the app does not load any content.*** A screenshot has been attached for your reference. **//Launch image is displayed.**

The steps to reproduce are:

1. Start the app on a device
2. The app displays a splash screen indefinitely

**Next Steps**

Please run your app on a device to identify the issue(s), then revise and resubmit your app for review.

If we misunderstood the intended behavior of your app, please reply to this message in the Resolution Center to provide information on how these features were intended to work.

For new apps, uninstall all previous versions of your app from a device, then install and follow the steps to reproduce the issue(s). For updates, install the new version as an update to the previous version, then follow the steps to reproduce the issue(s).

**Resources**

If you have difficulty reproducing a reported issue, please try testing the workflow described in Technical Q&A QA1764: How to reproduce bugs reported against App Store submissions.

If you have code-level questions after utilizing the above resources, you may wish to consult with Apple Developer Technical Support. When the DTS engineer follows up with you, please be ready to provide:
- complete details of your rejection issue(s)
- screenshots
- steps to reproduce the issue(s)
- symbolicated crash logs - if your issue results in a crash log

Comment: Your app is crashing, test it on the same device if possible or ask for the crash log.

Comment: @rckoenes : Thanks for ur quick response. I tested with same device, and followed their steps to reproduce it. But for me its working fine. So only am confused.

Comment: Hi guys, What i did mistake in this question?  why you put downvoting?

Comment: Ask Apple for the crash log.

Comment: It wouldn't sit on the splash screen indefinitely if it was crashing.  Sounds more like `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` is getting stuck somewhere and never returning.

Comment: @dan - Thanks for your response. I will check and let you know.

Comment: Does your app use internet ?

Comment: @ChaturaM - Thanks for your response. yes, my app was using internet, location services and Apple push notification.

Comment: Did you manage to solve the issue?